# Select2 multiple boxes not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have a laravel 5.4 project and I am trying to get the Select2 boxes working. The problem is that the are not picking up the select2.min.js file and the select2.min.css in the public folder. This is what it looks like.  For whatever reason I can't seem to reference the select2 files.

[image]

I have been wrestling with this for a couple of days.  I am trying to get this function to load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select2-multi').select2();
</script>`
```

I have tried putting it in the body but no success.
Below is my HTML:

```
    {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') }}
    <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    {{ Form::label('featured_img', 'Upload a Featured Image') }}
    {{ Form::file('featured_img') }}
    {{ Form::label('body', "Post Body:") }}
    {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;')) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my javascript:

```
{!! Html::script('js/parsley.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('js/select2.min.js') !!}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select2-multi').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Please share fiddle so that will be easier for solve the problem.

Comment: How do I "share fiddle"?

Comment: go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and past your coding and click save. Then  share the url. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/k4f184j5/1/

Comment: Does this make sense? Not used jsfiddle before. https://jsfiddle.net/amidabrian54/ghhudco2/

Comment: I can't find any select2 related coding??

Comment: That's my problem. I have referenced it. But can't seem to have access to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147093/discussion-between-altbrian-and-sarath-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you put it directly in HTML instead of include section.

Please try this link from JSbin: http://jsbin.com/huropeqora/edit?html,output

```
 $('.select2-multi').select2();
```